# Solve $x \frac{d^{2}y}{d x^{2}}+\frac{d y}{d x}+x y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> Solve the differential equation $$x \frac{d^{2}y}{d x^{2}}+\frac{d y}{d x}+x y=0$$

---

My try:

Let $z := x \frac{dy}{dx}$. So, we get $$\frac{dz}{dx}=x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dx}$$

and, thus,

$$\frac{dz}{dx}+xy=0$$

Any help from here?

Comment: Have a look at the Bessel differential equation. Explore a power series solution.

Comment: The solutions involve special functions, namely Bessel functions $I_0$ and $K_0$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function